# 0/1 Knapsack algorithm for optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem

My variables are;

```
customer = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)  
cost of the promotion = (10,20,30)  
availability of the promotions = (2,3,5)
profit = positive integers around 100  
the capacity of the knapsack = total budget
```

I want to maximize the profit by allocating one of the 3 promotions per customer. The capacity of the knapsack is the total budget. I have some constraints as well.

- The algorithm should allocate only one promotion to one customer.
- The algorithm should allocate all the promotions available.

---

I did it this way.
I made a list with all the combinations as follows and proceeded.

```
items = ((1,1,50),(1,2,78),(1,3,69),(2,1,45),(2,2,98),(2,3,47),(3,1,90),(3,2,36),(3,3,54),(4,1,35)...)
```

where:

```
items = (i,j,k)   :   
i = customer   
j = the promotion  
k = profit
```

But then there are dependent elements in the "items" list. (which belongs to the same customer) Knapsack algorithm treats the elements as independent so it does not work properly. It allocates two or more promotions to one customer.

Appreciate if anyone can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Is this really knapsack? The way I understand your question, you have to distribute exactly `(2,3,5)` promitions, with costs `(10,20,30)`, so the total cost will _always_ be 230, right? In fact, since the total cost is always the same, it does not matter at all. Instead, you just want to find the optimal profit.

Comment: Also, at least in the example you provided, there seem only to be about 2500 possible combinations to distribute the profits, so it would be easy to just enumerate them all and find the best one. How large are your actual problem instances?

Comment: @tobias_k My actual problem size is quite large. (around 100000) Am I doing wrong with knapsack? All I want to do is, to allocate promotions to customers. I have the available number of promotions, the cost of each promotion and the profit of each customer. I want to maximize the profit. should allocate only one promotion to one customer.